# Request works fine in Postman but Gives an Error Apache-JMETER

Tags: jmeter

I want to trigger a GET request as below-
http:{SomeServerName}/Path
Where in the Path i have passed variables as - ${BaseURI}${SerialNumber}${ParamList}
Which i am passed through a CSV file

The headers I am using are:
Content-Type, Authorization,Accept-Encoding, X-transactionId and X-siteId

On triggering the request with 1 thread in Apache J Meter I get this error-
 org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: xxx.tc.at.xxx.net:8443 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:850)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:561)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1282)

In Postman this works perfectly fine, but gives the above error in JMeter, can someone please help?
Also, I get the response after a lag of 8 seconds

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace it appears that JMeter fails to parse a [HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), it's hard to say what's wrong without seeing the response details, you can [increase JMeter logs verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) and look into the logs, most probably you will see the root cause there, add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change. Next time you start the request you should see full details on the request and response in the *jmeter.log* file.

Most probably it's a bug in the application you're testing as it returns malformed header(s).

---

You can try to work it around by changing "Implementation" for the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which is failing to `Java`

[image]

If you have more than 1 HTTP Request sampler the Implementation can be changed in one place if you use [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

But remember that even if it will work, it will be a **workaround**, the solution would be to understand which header cannot be parsed and fix it on the application side.